# Append Row in Sheets through Apps Script in Multiple Views

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am creating a web app using Google Apps Script. So this app basically is meant to send quotations to user by collecting various parameters. The deployment has 3 views. The first asks for Email and Plant Type. The second view asks for 4 parameters. The third view shows recommendation after some processing on server side along with other 2 inputs. 
The problem is that I have to append a row after the submit button is clicked on the third view. So that a new row is created in my linked google sheets as a database with all the inputs from user. The script was running fine when there was 1 view. But as I made 3 views, it's now not appending a new row in google sheets.
**The Object "Info" is where I am storing inputs from user.**
Here's the script:

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
  });
  var Info = {};
  
  document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click",dothis);
      
  function dothis(){

    Info.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    Info.ptype = document.getElementById("ptype").value;

    }
  document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click",thenthis);

  function thenthis(){
     
    Info.quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    Info.hotwt = document.getElementById("hotwt").value;
    Info.coldwt = document.getElementById("coldwt").value;
    Info.wetbt = document.getElementById("wetbt").value;

  }

  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",andthenthis);
  
  function andthenthis(){

    Info.recomcell = document.getElementById("recomcell").value;
    Info.prefercells = document.getElementById("prefercells").value;
    Info.coc = document.getElementById("coc").value;
        
    google.script.run.UserClicked(Info);
        
    document.getElementById("recomcell").value = "";
    M.updateTextFields();

    var mycoc = document.getElementById("coc");
    mycoc.selectedIndex = 0;
    M.FormSelect.init(mycoc);
    var myprefercells = document.getElementById("prefercells");
    myprefercells.selectedIndex = 0;
    M.FormSelect.init(myprefercells);
  }

  </script>
```

Here's the other part of the code:

```
function UserClicked(Info){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Database");

    ws.appendRow([Info.email,Info.ptype,Info.quantity,Info.hotwt,Info.coldwt,Info.wetbt,Info.recomcell,Info.prefercells,Info.coc,new Date()]);
     
}
```

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 3 view, but it would help to implment logs in each function to see if they are being called correctly and thus narrow down the problem.